# interpreter taking long time to process numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, numbers

i am trying to implement One Time Pad encryption, in the handshake procedure, the python stays too long to perform this

```
public = (private ** prime1) % prime2
```

where public is the number i intend to send 
private is a random 128 bit number generated by ramdom.getrandbits (128)
prime1 & prime2 are two common prime numbers 128bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you could use [the three-argument form of the `pow()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). It uses a more efficient algorithm for [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

```
public = pow(private, prime1, prime2)
```

However, I'm concerned by the way that you're describing this as being used for "one-time pad encryption". A one-time pad requires a random preshared key that is larger than the total size of all messages that will be transmitted. What you are implementing looks more like DH key exchange, which is not part of this process, and cannot be used for it.

Comment: thanks for the response, regarding your concern, yes it is indeed DH to share the OTP key, and using a pseudo random generator, the key will be enlarged, and OTP will be a part of the stream cipher

Comment: What you are describing is not a one-time pad. It is a stream cipher, and if it is using a noncryptographic PRNG, it is highly insecure.

Comment: interesting, add more info please

Comment: Many noncryptographic PRNGs have a seed size of 32 to 64 bits. This is woefully inadequate for security; an attacker can easily test every possible seed to search for one which decrypts your message. More generally, noncryptographic PRNGs are usually susceptible to known-plaintext attacks -- being able to know or guess part of the message (and, hence, to read some of the PRNG output) may be sufficient to predict its future and/or past output.

Comment: thanks alot, i will make sure to use a cryptographic PRG and the seed will be 32 bytes long  (128bits)

Comment: If you're going to go that route, you might as well go all the way and use a stream cipher. This is what they're made to do.

Comment: i will go that way